# Is jpaDerivedIdentifier deprecated?

Tags: jhipster

I noticed a code change of replacing jpaDerivedIdentifier with builtInEntity. To my understanding, they are for different subjects. In my experience, jpaDerivedIdentifier didn't work in practice. I assume the jpaDerivedIdentifier is deprecated and builtInEntity is for the 8.x version which currently is in beta. While adding a line of

```
 @OneToOne(mappedBy = "child")
```

isn't a big deal, keeping a proper document is.